# When using a date column, first and last bars are cut in half

Tags: google-visualization

When I use a column type of date, the first and last bars in the ColumnChart are cut in half.  It seems to be rendering from mid-bar.  It doesn't do this with non-date sets of data.

Is there any way to fix this so that the complete bars are rendered, with some extra padding?

http://jsfiddle.net/7tHVN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem (my labels were also weirdly misaligned) and it drove me crazy trying to figure it out. `hAxis.viewWindowMode` usually fixes issues like this, but it's not possible to use this with date values.

What I ended up doing was just scrapping the date type entirely, specifying the `string` type for that column instead, and converting each JS date object to a string representation before adding it to the `DataTable`, thusly:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Performance');

var dates = [new Date('2012-4-12'),
             new Date('2012-4-13'),
             new Date('2012-4-14')];
var performance = [59, 35, 86];

var dateString;
for (var i=0; i<dataForChart.length; i++) {
    dateString = (dates[i].getMonth()+1)+'/'+ // JS months are 0-indexed
                  dates[i].getDate()+'/'+
                  dates[i].getYear();
    data.addRow([dateString, 
                performance[i]]);
}
```

This forces the chart to render with a discrete rather than continuous axis, which fixes the cut-off bars problem. As long as your data and dates are spaced along even intervals (once a day, once a week, etc.) and you pass them in in the proper order, this approach should work.

There's more info on discrete vs. continuous axes in the Google Viz docs: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have already done this, but was hoping to go back to using Date's if I could find a solution.  I'll leave this open for a few more days and mark you as the solution if nobody else contributes anything.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the viewWindowMode does work for dates, apparently. Adding the following to my chart options, where the min and max are dates prior to and beyond the 1st and last date values, worked for me, at least.

```
'hAxis': {'viewWindowMode': 'explicit', 'viewWindow': {'max':new Date('2012-10-02'), 'min':new Date('2007-07-02')}}
```

See also: [Column Chart crops the end bars](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!search/first%2420and%2420last%2420bars%2420in%2420the%2420ColumnChart/google-visualization-api/EdP7wUCkcxY/m_WJ6ZEgwXgJ) in the Google forums.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Fix here 
If you double click on the first column to access the Format Data Point you can widen the individual column width to match the same visibility as the other columns.  Same applies to the last column when 'cut off' due to date and axis

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug on Excel, easy fix, change the graph type to stacked bar, then switch back to stacked column, and your graph will be fixed.